# Get Unique rows based on values and sort by Time

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, unique

I have the following table. I want to get 1 of each source order by Time (asc). Source is not fixed - it could be anything

```
Time                    |Source
------------------------------------
2012-08-18 05:00:03.000 | A
2012-08-19 06:00:03.000 | B
2012-08-18 06:00:03.000 | B
2012-08-20 06:00:03.000 | C
2012-08-21 06:00:03.000 | A
```

So based on the above table ill get the below result

```
Time                    |Source
------------------------------------
2012-08-18 05:00:03.000 | A
2012-08-18 06:00:03.000 | B
2012-08-20 06:00:03.000 | C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, source, min(time) t 
from table 
group by source, id
order by t
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. What would happen if there was an extra filed Say "ID". to give [ID|Time|Source]. how would you handle the "ID". Would i need to add a aggregate for "ID"

Comment: Yes. Just add the `ID` to the `select` and `group by`. See updated answer.

Comment: The code without `id` works. With `id` and if it is the primary key of the table, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `MIN()` aggregate function and `GROUP BY` your source value.  So I believe this will do what you want. (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4b5f/2))

```
select min([time]) minTime, source
from yourTable
group by source
order by minTime
```